# Exception.StackTrace is null in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException - Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, exception, unhandled-exception

I'm using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException to catch all the unhandled exceptions in my Xamarin.Droid project. But receiving null for Exception.StackTrace.
I have the following code inside a class which extends Application

```
//Inside constructor
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleExceptions;

static void HandleExceptions(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) 
{
    Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
    Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: ", e.StackTrace);
}
```

What should I do to get the StackTrace of the exception?

Comment: Check exception’s InnerException property. Is it null or not?

Comment: InnerException property too is null.